# I don't understand how to import geopandas in pyscript after have downloaded and installed it from a whl

Tags: python, geopandas, pyscript

I'm starting to learn something about PyScript and my objective is to work with geospatial data. I tried to install geopanda using `<py-env>- geopandas</py-env>`and found out that it's not possibile.

So I switched to `.whl`, downloading it from `https://pypi.org/project/geopandas/` and seems alright (I'm using a XAMPP localhost).

```
<py-env>
        - './wheels/geopandas-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
</py-env>
```

However, this is the first time that I use `.whl`, so I don't understand what I should do to import geopandas from `.whl`. To better explain me:

```
<py-script>
            import folium
            import json
            # here I would import geopandas

            m = folium.Map(location=[45, 7], tiles='stamentoner')
            m

</py-script>
```

In Chrome Browser, the error looks like this:

```
JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, in eval_code .run(globals, locals) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) File "", line 3, in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas' )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) You would use the statement **import geopandas** as per the documentation. 2) What error are you getting when you put geopandas in `<py-env>`? If it does not work there, manually specifying a wheel will not work either. 3) I wrote a document on how to detect PyScript errors and how to manage them: https://www.jhanley.com/pyscript-debugging-and-error-management-strategies/

Comment: I have a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'` only if I add to my code `<py-script> import geopandas </py-script>` .Without this line,  `<py-env>` does not show any error. In Chrome browser that I'm using I visualize a `JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, in eval_code .run(globals, locals) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals) File "", line 3, in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas' )`

Comment: Please put those details in your question and not in the comments. Too hard to read.

Comment: You can only import modules that are either pure Python 3 wheels or ones that have been ported by the Pyodide team to Wasm. Based upon a quick review of geopandas, it has dependencies that are not compatible with the browser API.

Comment: Open the Chrome debugger. If you have correctly specified the package in the `<py-env>` tag, then you will see the geopandas package being downloaded. If not you have made a mistake. You must specify both the `<py-env>` tag and `import geopandas`. One without the other will not work.

Comment: Is this a copy and paste error: **- './wheels/geopandas-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl' python -m http.server**. Why is **python -m http.server** on the line?

Comment: Is there some solution ? I have same error message with any module I try to import. folium and pandas. The error states a path which does not exists on my system. How can you set the script to look in the right path (windows  AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\)? thanks